# C# противоречия в наследовании и инкапсуляции

Tags: c#, наследование, инкапсуляция

Итак, имеется два класса: один родительский, второй дочерний.

```
class FirstClass
{
    private int i; //как я понимаю, теперь эту переменую унаследовать нельзя
    public void ShowNumber()
    {
        i = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}


class SecondClass : FirstClass
{

}

static void main()
{
    SecondCLass second = new SecondClass();
    second.ShowNumber();
}
```

Консоль:

> 10

Каким образом дочерний клас получил доступ к private полю родительского класа если он доступен исключительно в родительском классе?

Comment: Он не получил доступ к `private` полю класса-предка (почему Вы так решили, и что значит доступ?).  Используя объект наследника можно вызвать `public` метод базового класса, а что уж там базовый класс делает, известно только тому, кто этот метод написал.

Comment: @Igor тоесть поля и методы помечены модификатором private тоже наследуются дочерним класом?

Comment: Конечно, наследуются. Только обратиться к ним (напрямую) из кода наследника нельзя.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо за ответ.